# how can I install GD library on Ubuntu 14.x?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Hi I can't find any GD library name and how to download it to my Ubunto Version 14.x
I've already tried php7.1-gd or libgd but in vain...

thank you for you answer in advance.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35560150/php-gd-bundled-extension-without-recompiling-php-solution

Comment: https://www.codexworld.com/ubuntu-install-php-gd-extension-support-apache-web-server/

Comment: 14.xx are EOL and you're unlikely to find any packages for that, esp something like php 7 which is provided as a PPA https://www.patreon.com/posts/ubuntu-14-04-lts-26560500